# How to exclude subfolders with specific titles from robocopy in CMD?

Tags: cmd, robocopy

**Thank you in advance for any advice.** *(unfortunately, i only have a very rudimentary knowledge of cmd.)*

I have just copied a folder structure with subfolders without file contents from a directory to create a template folder (using cmd.exe). However, this also copies subfolders that I will not need.

Ideally, I would like to do exclude them by using a .txt file, as it can happen that i don't need a list of subfolders and typing them in individually in cmd.exe is tedious.

**Copying the folders worked and gave me as output:**

```
   C:\Windows\system32>robocopy "I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021" "C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\test" /MIR /NOCOPY

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Donnerstag, 10. Juni 2021 15:14:36
   Quelle : I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\
     Ziel : C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\test\

    Dateien : *.*

  Optionen: *.* /S /E /NOCOPY /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\
         Neues Verz.       7    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Allgemeines Modell\
         Neues Verz.      21    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Beschriftung\
         Neues Verz.      11    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Beschriftung\_Archiv\
         Neues Verz.       3    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fassadenelemente\
         Neues Verz.      33    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fenster\
         Neues Verz.      12    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fenstertür\
         Neues Verz.      12    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Möbel\
         Neues Verz.       2    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Parkplatz\
         Neues Verz.       3    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Profil\
         Neues Verz.       6    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\TGA Sanitär\
         Neues Verz.      15    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Türen\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertÜbersprungenKeine Übereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:        12        11         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:       125         0       125         0         0         0
    Bytes:   85.35 m         0   85.35 m         0         0         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Beendet: Donnerstag, 10. Juni 2021 15:14:37
```

**Reading the lines in .txt file was also possible:**

```
   C:\Windows\system32>type C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\withoutDirectories.txt
 _Archiv
 _NESTED
```

*I tried this approach, but it seems, that this excludes the .txt from beeing copied, 
not the Subfolders with the specified names in .txt -file:*

```
    C:\Windows\system32>robocopy "I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021" "C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\test" /MIR /NOCOPY /XD dirs C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\withoutDirectories.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Donnerstag, 10. Juni 2021 15:53:31
   Quelle : I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\
     Ziel : C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\test\

    Dateien : *.*

 Ausgeschl. Verzeichnisse: dirs
            C:\Users\dfeyer\Desktop\withoutDirectories.txt

  Optionen: *.* /S /E /NOCOPY /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\
         Neues Verz.       7    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Allgemeines Modell\
         Neues Verz.      21    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Beschriftung\
         Neues Verz.      11    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Beschriftung\_Archiv\
         Neues Verz.       3    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fassadenelemente\
         Neues Verz.      33    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fenster\
         Neues Verz.      12    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Fenstertür\
         Neues Verz.      12    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Möbel\
         Neues Verz.       2    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Parkplatz\
         Neues Verz.       3    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Profil\
         Neues Verz.       6    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\TGA Sanitär\
         Neues Verz.      15    I:\BIM\Bibliothek\05_Familien\529_TFS_2021\Türen\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertÜbersprungenKeine Übereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:        12        11         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:       125         0       125         0         0         0
    Bytes:   85.35 m         0   85.35 m         0         0         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Beendet: Donnerstag, 10. Juni 2021 15:53:32
```

---

**How can I link the lines of code so that unwanted subfolders named "_Archiv" & "NESTED" won´t be  copied?**

---

Comment: robocopy requires the exclusions to be passed on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will read through the documentation.